# Need assistance in using round on a current query

Tags: sql, rounding, pgadmin-4

```
SELECT
    (TS_LEXIZE('english_stem',
               UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(
                   REGEXP_REPLACE(feedback, '[^a-zA-Z]+', ' ', 'g'),
                   ' ')
               )))[1] AS token,
    AVG(rating) AS avg_rating
FROM customer_survey 
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(1) >= 3
ORDER BY 2 DESC
;
```

I have the following query where would you add ROUND () if you want to limit the rating to 2 decimal places?

Comment: Tis looks like neither MySQL nor SQL Server.  I removed the inconsistent tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    (TS_LEXIZE('english_stem',
               UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(
                   REGEXP_REPLACE(feedback, '[^a-zA-Z]+', ' ', 'g'),
                   ' ')
               )))[1] AS token,
    ROUND(AVG(rating)) AS avg_rating
FROM customer_survey 
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(1) >= 3
ORDER BY 2 DESC
;
```

By adding the round before the avg I got it.